# Read contents of MemoryCache including Expiry times

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, memorycache

Is it possible to extract contents of a `MemoryCache` object, including:

1. Cache Item key
2. Cache Item value
3. Cache Item expiry time
   ?

Answer (score 1):

Extracting Cache Item keys and values is easy and is covered elsewhere on the Internet. After some research, it appears that **there is** a way to extract **expiry times** for each item. We have to use Reflection, because the framework does not expose `MemoryCache`'s internal objects.

We will first create a class to store information for each Cache Item:

```
    public class MemoryCacheItemInfo
    {
        public string Key { get; private set; }
        public object CacheItemValue { get; private set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; private set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdateUsage { get; private set; }
        public DateTime AbsoluteExpiry { get; private set; }
        public TimeSpan SlidingExpiry { get; private set; }

        public MemoryCacheItemInfo(string key, object cacheItemValue,
            DateTime created, DateTime lastUpdateUsage, DateTime absoluteExpiry,
            TimeSpan slidingExpiry)
        {
            this.Key = key;
            this.CacheItemValue = cacheItemValue;
            this.Created = created;
            this.LastUpdateUsage = lastUpdateUsage;
            this.AbsoluteExpiry = absoluteExpiry;
            this.SlidingExpiry = slidingExpiry;
        }
    }
```

Now, we will use Reflection to access private `MemoryCache` fields:

```
    public static MemoryCacheItemInfo[] GetCacheItemInfo(this MemoryCache cache)
    {
        BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        FieldInfo field = typeof (MemoryCache).GetField("_stores", bindFlags);
        object[] cacheStores = (object[]) field.GetValue(cache);

        List<MemoryCacheItemInfo> info = new List<MemoryCacheItemInfo>();

        foreach (object cacheStore in cacheStores)
        {
            Type cacheStoreType = cacheStore.GetType();

            FieldInfo lockField = cacheStoreType.GetField("_entriesLock", bindFlags);

            object lockObj = lockField.GetValue(cacheStore);

            lock (lockObj)
            {

                FieldInfo entriesField = cacheStoreType.GetField("_entries", bindFlags);
                Hashtable entriesCollection = (Hashtable) entriesField.GetValue(cacheStore);

                foreach (DictionaryEntry cacheItemEntry in entriesCollection)
                {
                    Type cacheItemValueType = cacheItemEntry.Value.GetType();

                    string key = (string) cacheItemEntry.Key.GetType().GetProperty("Key", bindFlags).GetValue(cacheItemEntry.Key);

                    PropertyInfo value = cacheItemValueType.GetProperty("Value", bindFlags);
                    PropertyInfo utcCreated = cacheItemValueType.GetProperty("UtcCreated", bindFlags);
                    PropertyInfo utcLastUpdateUsage = cacheItemValueType.GetProperty("UtcLastUpdateUsage", bindFlags);
                    PropertyInfo utcAbsoluteExpiry = cacheItemValueType.GetProperty("UtcAbsExp", bindFlags);
                    PropertyInfo utcSlidingExpiry = cacheItemValueType.GetProperty("SlidingExp", bindFlags);

                    MemoryCacheItemInfo mcii = new MemoryCacheItemInfo(
                        key,
                        value.GetValue(cacheItemEntry.Value),
                        ((DateTime) utcCreated.GetValue(cacheItemEntry.Value)).ToLocalTime(),
                        ((DateTime) utcLastUpdateUsage.GetValue(cacheItemEntry.Value)).ToLocalTime(),
                        ((DateTime) utcAbsoluteExpiry.GetValue(cacheItemEntry.Value)).ToLocalTime(),
                        ((TimeSpan) utcSlidingExpiry.GetValue(cacheItemEntry.Value))
                        );

                    info.Add(mcii);
                }

            }
        }

        return info.ToArray();
    }
```

This approach is **not efficient** and is not recommended for production environments.

Also, accessing `MemoryCache` private fields is not officially supported by Microsoft. Internal structure of `MemoryCache` object may change in future, which will break this code.